# How to get non matching records in sql server in same table?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table say `StudentBillDetails` and in this table data is saved annually and `yrid` is referenced to some other table. Now I am stuck with a problem. I want to retrieve non matching records as described below.

```
Stid    BillNo  Yrid
1        525    3
1        525    1
1        525    4
2        443    4
2        442    1
2        443    3
```

In above given table structure as you can see for three years `StId 1` has same value but `StId 2` has a confliction in `Yrid 1`. So I want to get these type of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to flag `Stid` values which have conflicts then the following simple query should work:

```
SELECT Stid
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Stid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT BillNo) > 1
```

If you want the entire records you could try joining your table to the above query:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
( SELECT Stid FROM yourTable GROUP BY Stid HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT BillNo) > 1 ) t2
    ON t1.Stid = t2.Stid
```